# Can a constructor created with new call itself?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have this script:

```
function myFunction() {
    this.function = function() {
        ...
    };

    this.function2 = function() {
        ...
    };
}

var foo = new myFunction();
```

I want `foo.function()` to call `foo.function2()` but I can't figure out how to do it. `this.function2()` didn't seem to work, and I don't want to use `foo.function2()` because then if I add `var foo2 = new myFunction()` it wouldn't work. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: If you reorder them to place the creation and assignment of `this.function2` before `this.function`, then it'd be possible. But it seems like [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I didn't think of that! But I realized that now I need `foo.function2()` to call `foo.function()` as well. Are there any ways to do that?

Comment: This is the time to step back and explain what you're actually trying to do because it seems overly complicated.

Comment: It looks like this is a design flaw. It doesn't make sense to create instances of the constructor, and then call some methods inside another method depending on when the instance was created. If you'd explained the use-case, we might find a working alternative for the task.

Comment: do you have an actual error message you're getting? if you're just trying to call `this.function2()` inside of `function()`, that should work just fine as is. or maybe I'm unclear on what you're trying to do.

Comment: Have you tried to put the two functions in an array and let each function find the other not by name, but by array index? Essentially to create a class within class so that might help too.

Answer (score 0):

So I'm not getting the issue here, do you have an error message or can you clarify the problem? the below runs just fine as is.

```js
function myFunction() {
    this.function = function() {
        console.log('run 1')
        this.function2();
    };

    this.function2 = function() {
        console.log('run 2')
    };
}

var foo = new myFunction();
foo.function();
```

Comment: The logic was explained a bit more accurately in a comment. When they'll create another instance of the constructor, and call `function2` method, that should call `function` method. If you make that possible, it'll lead to infinite recursion (unless the caller isn't somehow recognized). What should happen, if a third instance will be created is unknown.

Comment: @Teemu not *necessarily* infinite as there can be a stop condition but...it does sound very suspicious here. I can't really solve the problem because I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: @VLAZ Yes, that's what I meant with recognized caller. The question is odd, and the title is even more weird, as it doesn't seem to fit to the text at all.

Comment: @Teemu would you say it's...illogical :P

Comment: @VLAZ Definitely yes!